# Excel function to count files in folder above certain value (filenames are numbers)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, filenames

I have the following code that counts how many files are in a directory:

```
Function FileCount(ByVal ImageType As String) As Variant

Dim FSO As Object, Files As Object

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Files = FSO.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Images\" & ImageType).Files

FileCount = Files.Count - 1

End Function
```

It is somewhat dynamic - it is restricted to a folder of images in the same directory as the Excel file, but the subdirectory can be changed by way of an input variable (*ImageType*) when typing the formula in a cell.

All of the images within each subdirectory are numbered, and the code above counts all files in the directory regardless of filename or filetype (all images are .jpg). The line `FileCount = Files.Count - 1` has the minus 1 part to adjust for the 'off by one error' for information.

However, I would like to be able to count how many files are numbered above a certain value (eg. any file with a name greater than 1000). Is there a simple way to adapt this code to do that? I do not need the value (eg. 1000) to be an input to the function, only that it needs to be specified in the code somewhere.

Thanks, hope this is explained sufficiently.

Comment: So the files are named (eg) "567.jpg", and all follow the same pattern?  `Val(File.Name)`  will give you the number for each file, which you can test to see if it's greater than (eg) 1000

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. The files are named like '1.jpg', '567.jpg', '931.jpg', '1031.jpg', etc. All positive numbers. Some are not integers, but that shouldn't be an issue as we're just doing a inequality comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a loop and `Val()`

```vb
Function FileCount(ByVal ImageType As String) As Variant

    Dim FSO As Object, Files As Object, f As Object, n As Long
    
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    For Each f In FSO.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Images\" & ImageType).Files
        If Val(f.Name) > 1000 Then n = n + 1
    Next f

    FileCount = n

End Function
```

Comment: This looks perfect. I will test this and get back to you. Looks nice and simple.

Comment: I've tested this code and it is exactly what I needed, and works without adjustment. Thank you.